# powerpoint search box vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to code some vba in powerpoint to search for a word in the slideshow and then go to that slide and format the word in some way so that it stands out.  So far I have add an activex textbox and used the below code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger,ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oshp As Shape
    Dim b_found As Boolean

    If KeyCode = 13 Then 'ENTER PRESSED
        If Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
                    If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
                        If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            If InStr(UCase(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange), UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text))>0     Then
                                SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (osld.SlideIndex)
                                Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
                                b_found = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next oshp
                If b_found = True Then Exit For
            Next osld
        End If
        If b_found = False Then MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine for finding the slide with the word on but doesn't format the word.  Any ideas??

Comment: I encourage you to format the code to be more readable, it is really hard to follow the way it is right now

Comment: Thanks for foing that Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that you can pick apart and use bits of:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

sTextToFind = "Text"

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                If InStr(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind) > 0 Then
                    Set oTxtRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind), Len(sTextToFind))
                    Debug.Print oTxtRng.Text
                    With oTxtRng
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Basically, the idea is to find the text (as you've already done) then get a range that represents the found text and format the range to suit.  In this case, by turning it bold.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @steverindsberg

In case anyone would like to know what I ended up using, I have amalgamted both codes into:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger,     ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim b_found As Boolean
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

sTextToFind = Me.TextBox1.Text


 If KeyCode = 13 Then 'ENTER PRESSED
     If Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
         For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
             For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
                 If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
                     If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                         If InStr(UCase(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange),    UCase (Me.TextBox1.Text)) > 0 Then
                         SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (osld.SlideIndex)
                         Set oTxtRng = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind), Len(sTextToFind))
                         Debug.Print oTxtRng.Text
                         With oTxtRng
                          .Font.Bold = True
                     End With

                 b_found = True
              Exit For
           End If
        End If
     End If
   Next oshp
   If b_found = True Then Exit For
 Next osld
End If
If b_found = False Then MsgBox "Not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!